# How to delete botched symbolic links in the registry

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I'm prototyping some edits to the registry to create a symbolic link from one area to another. I've used the following code:

```
HKEY hkFS;
HKEY hkSOFTWARE;
DWORD dwDisposition;
LSTATUS result;
result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE"), 0,
         KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY , &hkSOFTWARE);
if (result == 0) {
   result = RegOpenKeyEx(hkSOFTWARE, _T("MyKey"), REG_OPTION_OPEN_LINK,
            KEY_WRITE | KEY_CREATE_LINK | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hkFS);
   if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
      _tprintf(_T("%d\n"), result);
      result = RegCreateKeyEx(hkSOFTWARE, _T("MyKey"), 0, NULL,
               REG_OPTION_CREATE_LINK,
               KEY_WRITE | KEY_CREATE_LINK | KEY_WOW64_64KEY,
               NULL, &hkFS, &dwDisposition);
      _tprintf(_T("%d\n"), result);
   }
   if (result == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
      //result = ZwDeleteKey(hkFS);
      TCHAR target[] = _T("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\MyKey");
      result = RegSetValueEx(hkFS, _T("SymbolicLinkValue"), 0, REG_SZ,
               (const BYTE const *)target, sizeof(target));
      if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
         TCHAR msg[256];
         FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, result, 0, msg,
                       sizeof(msg) / sizeof(TCHAR), NULL);
         _tprintf(_T("Failed to write SymbolicLinkValue: %s"), msg);
      }
      RegCloseKey(hkFS);
   }
   else {
      TCHAR msg[256];
      FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, result, 0, msg,
                    sizeof(msg) / sizeof(TCHAR), NULL);
      _putts(msg);
   }
}
else {
   TCHAR msg[256];
   FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL, result, 0, msg,
                 sizeof(msg) / sizeof(TCHAR), NULL);
   _tprintf(_T("Error opening SOFTWARE: %s"), msg);
}
RegCloseKey(hkSOFTWARE);
```

And now I have 2 problems.

1. I cannot delete the MyKey values that have been created under SOFTWARE.
2. I get Access Denied errors when attempting to write SymbolicLinkValue to MyKey, even when running as administrator.

I need help cleaning up my registry and making this code work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found code at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11973/Registry-Symbolic-Links that solved all my problems.

This is the code it uses to delete a registry key representing a symbolic link:

```
typedef LONG NTSTATUS;

#if !defined(_NTSYSTEM_)
#define NTSYSAPI     DECLSPEC_IMPORT
#else
#define NTSYSAPI
#endif

NTSYSAPI
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
ZwDeleteKey(
    IN HANDLE KeyHandle
    );

typedef NTSYSAPI NTSTATUS  (NTAPI *ZW_DELETE_KEY_PROTO)(HANDLE);
static LONG DynZwDeleteKey(HKEY hKey)
{
    LONG lStatus = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    HMODULE hNTDll = LoadLibraryW( L"ntdll.dll" );
    if (hNTDll)
    {
      ZW_DELETE_KEY_PROTO lpfnZwDeleteKey =  (ZW_DELETE_KEY_PROTO)GetProcAddress(hNTDll, "ZwDeleteKey");
      if (lpfnZwDeleteKey)
        lStatus = lpfnZwDeleteKey(hKey);
      else
        lStatus = GetLastError();

      VERIFY(FreeLibrary(hNTDll));
    }
    else
        lStatus = GetLastError();

    return lStatus;
}
```

And my code above had a couple problems in creating the link.
These corrected lines make it work:

```
result = RegCreateKeyEx(hkSOFTWARE, _T("MyKey"), 0, NULL,
         REG_OPTION_CREATE_LINK,
         KEY_ALL_ACCESS | KEY_CREATE_LINK | KEY_WOW64_64KEY,
         NULL, &hkFS, &dwDisposition);
```

...

```
result = RegSetValueExW(hkFS, L"SymbolicLinkValue", 0, REG_LINK,
         (const BYTE const *)target, lstrlen(target) * sizeof(WCHAR));
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code for link creation will work perfectly for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, in case your path has a different key, use the following

```
//HKEY_USERS
TCHAR target[] = _T("\\Registry\\USER\\SOFTWARE\\MyKey");
//HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
TCHAR target[] = _T("\\Registry\\MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\MyKey");
//HKEY_CURRENT_USER
TCHAR target[] = _T("\\Registry\\USER\\CurrentUser\\SOFTWARE\\MyKey");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough karma to commment.... but AFAIK you cannot use a normal RegKeyDelete on a symlink. When you create key with the symlink flag, windows marks the container as a symlink and all further operations will be done on the target. I don't think user mode has enough granularity to specify that you want the operation done on the acutual container of the symlink and not the target.

You can call ZwOpenKey and give it a OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES struct that has the OBJ_OPENLINK  flag

> If an object handle, with this flag set, is passed to a routine that
>   opens objects and if the object is a symbolic link object, the routine
>   should open the symbolic link object itself, rather than the object
>   that the symbolic link refers to (which is the default behavior).

You can then do any of the operations you want with that handle.