# How to delete registry symbolic link key from C#: "An error is preventing this key from being opened. Details: Access is denied"

Tags: c#, winapi, registry, registrykey

I created a symbolic registry key by using the [NtObjectManager library](https://github.com/googleprojectzero/sandbox-attacksurface-analysis-tools/tree/main/NtObjectManager) like that:

```cs
using NtApiDotNet;
using System;

namespace poc
{
    class Program
    {
        const string SrcKey = @"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\ABC";
        const string TargetKey = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\XYZ";

        static NtKey CreateSymbolicLink(string name, string target)
        {
            name = NtKeyUtils.Win32KeyNameToNt(name);
            target = NtKeyUtils.Win32KeyNameToNt(target);
            return NtKey.CreateSymbolicLink(name, null, target);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var link = CreateSymbolicLink(SrcKey, TargetKey)
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried to delete the key from Registry (`Regedit.exe`) it failed with error:

> ABC cannot be opened. An error is preventing this key from being
> opened. Details: Access is denied

I tried to delete it even with `SYSTEM` permissions (using `psexec` to launch a `SYSTEM` cmd) but I still received the same error.

The function `NtKey.CreateSymbolicLink` is [calling](https://github.com/googleprojectzero/sandbox-attacksurface-analysis-tools/blob/c02ed8ba04324e54a0a188ab9877ee6aa372dfac/NtApiDotNet/NtKey.cs#L529) `SetSymbolicLinkTarget` which calls [eventually](https://github.com/googleprojectzero/sandbox-attacksurface-analysis-tools/blob/c02ed8ba04324e54a0a188ab9877ee6aa372dfac/NtApiDotNet/NtKey.cs#L1053-L1066) to `SetValue` like that:

```
SetValue(SymbolicLinkValueName, RegistryValueType.Link, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(target), throw_on_error);
```

I didn't figure out yet how to delete it.
I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29633906) about deleting symbolic registry key with C++ but it just calls `lpfnZwDeleteKey` and I don't know what is the equivalent to C#.

I tried the function `NtKey.UnloadKey` function, I thought it might help but it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to delete it using James's tool `CreateRegSymlink` like that:

```
CreateRegSymlink.exe -d "HKCU\Software\XYZ"
```

I noticed that it is being done by [calling](https://github.com/googleprojectzero/symboliclink-testing-tools/blob/00c0fe4cefcd2a62c887fe6117abc02bc98bb9fb/CreateRegSymlink/CreateRegSymlink.cpp#L37) `DeleteRegSymlink`.
When I checked what is [inside it](https://github.com/googleprojectzero/symboliclink-testing-tools/blob/00c0fe4cefcd2a62c887fe6117abc02bc98bb9fb/CommonUtils/RegistrySymlink.cpp#L181), I noticed it convert the registry path to a real path by calling `RegPathToNative`:

```
bstr_t symlink = RegPathToNative(lpSymlink);
```

[Here](https://github.com/googleprojectzero/symboliclink-testing-tools/blob/00c0fe4cefcd2a62c887fe6117abc02bc98bb9fb/CommonUtils/RegistrySymlink.cpp#L92-L119) you can see what the `RegPathToNative` work.
Then it calls:

```
InitializeObjectAttributes(&obj_attr, &name, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE | OBJ_OPENLINK, nullptr, nullptr);
```

Which is I think where the magic happens.
If you have any suggestion how to find the real link from a symbolic registry path, let me know.

---

**EDIT(10/1/2022) - thanks to @RbMm:**
I created a function to open symlink using `REG_OPTION_OPEN_LINK` and then deletes it with `ZwDeleteKey` but the important thing was to set the rights to `RegistryRights.Delete` as @RbMm mentioned:

```
const int REG_OPTION_OPEN_LINK = 0x0008;

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, BestFitMapping = false, ExactSpelling = true)]
static extern int RegOpenKeyExW(SafeRegistryHandle hKey, String lpSubKey,
    int ulOptions, int samDesired, out SafeRegistryHandle hkResult);


[DllImport("ntdll.dll")]  
private static extern int ZwDeleteKey(SafeRegistryHandle hKey);  


public static RegistryKey OpenSubKeySymLink(this RegistryKey key, string name, RegistryRights rights = RegistryRights.ReadKey, RegistryView view = 0)
{
    var error = RegOpenKeyExW(key.Handle, name, REG_OPTION_OPEN_LINK, ((int)rights) | ((int)view), out var subKey);
    if (error != 0)
    {
        subKey.Dispose();
        throw new Win32Exception(error);
    }
    return RegistryKey.FromHandle(subKey);  // RegistryKey will dispose subKey
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RegistryKey key;
    key = OpenSubKeySymLink(Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser, @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\ABC", RegistryRights.Delete, 0);
    ZwDeleteKey(key.Handle);
}
```

Comment: you can use [`RegOpenKeyExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopenkeyexw) with option `REG_OPTION_OPEN_LINK` for open key itself (not linked key) and than `ZwDeleteKey`

Comment: @RbMm I updated my answer "EDIT(10/1/2022)", I tried to use what you wrote but it still doesn't delete the symlink key.

Comment: if you open correct key, with `DELETE` access and no subkeys - it of course delete key. so first check - which key you actually open - symlink key or it target

Comment: @RbMm Great! I just needed to change the rights to `DELETE` like you wrote. Thank you very much !